# Process not listed in list of modules

Tags: windbg

I am debugging two processes:

```
.  0    id: 5d50    attach  name: PMGRWIN.exe
   1    id: 2e50    child   name: MB64.exe
```

I am trying to figure out the version number of MB64.exe. So I did a `lmvm mb64`. No information was shown.

I then tried to figure out whether the executable got a different name. So I did a `lmf` and searched for `.exe`. However, there's only one search result:

[image: Screenshot of search result]

How can I find the module name of the executable so that I can display it with `lmv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lm` only shows the names of the modules of the currently selected process. This <strike>is</strike> was [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/lm--list-loaded-modules-).

You were on `|0s`, which is `PMGRWIN` (indicated by the `.` in the output of `|`) and it only shows the modules of that process.
In order to find `MB64`, switch to the other process with `|1s`.

Interestingly, you can't temporarily switch to process 1 and run the command there. `|1 lmvm mb64` does not work either, even if the name of the module is `mb64`.

With [issue 3557](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-driver-docs/issues/3557) the documentation has been enhanced:

> The modules displayed depends on how you are debugging, for example user or kernel mode, and the specific context you are looking at. For more information about the process context and other context settings, see Changing Contexts and Controlling Processes and Threads.